More than one adjective for a noun separated by comma
I am of the notion that when you mention more than one adjective for a noun, you separate them with commas and finally an and before the last one. 
#1 eg: the evening, gloomy, rainy and cold.
If there are only two, you separate them using an "and" 
#2 eg: the evening, gloomy and rainy.
If I were to place them before the noun, I would write:
#3 the gloomy and rainy evening.
However, Grammarly and other AI based writing helper sites correct the #3 as  the gloomy, rainy evening.
WHy is it so? Is it okay to write like the above? Doesn't it need an 'and'?
Does placement determine this or is there any other rule to be considered?

I don't know where you have got the idea that two adjectives always have to be separated by and. This is only the case if they follow the noun.

@KateBunting - My Big Fat Greek Wedding - not a comma or 'and' to be seen.

@MichaelHarvey - Yes, big and little don't even need a comma when combined with another adjective. Dunno if there are any more like that.

@KateBunting because they are two distinct words that describe two different attributes of the noun. Isn;t it the reason why we separate them when they follow a noun? Why doesn't that apply when they precede the noun is my question

I don't really know why It was a gloomy, rainy evening sounds natural but The evening was gloomy, rainy doesn't. I think you could follow a noun with two adjectives without and, but it would sound like 'poetic', 'literary' language, not ordinary speech.

My exciting hot steamy afternoon. My afternoon: exciting, hot, and steamy.

New green crocheted sweater. Again, no commas required—or (here) even permissible. And it would be very odd (if syntactically acceptable) to write, *“The sweater is new, green, and crocheted,” even though “The sweater is ADJ” would be fine where ADJ was any one of new, green, and crocheted.

@PaulTanenbaum Can you explain why a comma next to New isn't permissible?

@KateBunting Big, little, New (as mentioned by Paul) what else doesn't need commas? Is there a guide to these that I can look up?

I found this which goes some way to explain. Re: Paul's comment - You could say "The new sweater is green and crocheted", where the last two adjectives describe its physical appearance but new doesn't.

There are several related questions about lists of adjectives, e.g. this and this but they seem to require more knowledge than the OP has.

One important point: Your #3 was grammatically valid (assuming it worked right with the rest of the sentence. The AI advice was not correcting an error; by moving the descriptors before the noun, it was just suggesting a stylistic improvement that might flow better.

The classic example of adjectives that don't need commas is "lovely little old rectangular green French silver whittling knife". It's not a hard and fast rule but native speakers often order adjectives like this: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order

That was helpful @Kaia, thanks.


I am of the notion that when you mention more than one adjective for a noun, you separate them with commas and finally an and before the last one.

That's partially correct, but not for all types of adjectives and not in all contexts.
If the adjectives are coordinate adjectives - ie adjectives that independently modify the noun and are of equal importance - then you separate them by commas.  For example "it was a cold, gloomy, rainy evening".
As you can see, there is no need to use 'and' before the last adjective when phrased this way around, but if you write it the other way then yes, you need to - ie "the evening was cold, gloomy and rainy".
Interestingly, I was taught that you can identify coordinate adjectives using 'the "and" test'. Basically, if you can join two adjectives with 'and' instead of a comma without changing the meaning, then they can be comma-separated.
But cumulative adjectives should not be comma separated - for example, "a bright red dress". Cumulative adjectives build upon each other and are not of equal importance. The dress is "bright red", not "bright and red".
Also, when adjectives belong to different categories (eg adjectives of size, shape, colour etc) then they are not comma separated - for example "a big red ball".
You asked why adjectives are comma separated - I don't think there is an authoritative answer to that, but when you understand that coordinate adjectives are of equal importance and independent it makes sense that they are considered separately rather than cumulatively. For example, if you said "a white lace dress" it would mean the dress was made of lace that was white, whereas "a white, lace dress" means a dress that is both white and made of lace.

It might also be worth addressing one thing that seems to be confusing the OP: everything above is for when the adjectives precede the noun. If they are glued on after it, everything the OP wrote to begin with is true; you do need "and" and serial commas as needed.

@AndyBonner Hmm, no, I think you're wrong. You would say "the dress was white lace", not "white and lace".

Well, isn't "lace" a modifying noun there? E.g,, it wouldn't work with "lacy."

@AndyBonner sure, 'lace' is a noun so it is behaving as an adjectival noun when you say "lace dress", but 'lacy' as you suggest would mean it was lace-like, or featuring some lace rather than actually made of lace. I think you're going off-topic.

On the contrary, I'm trying to circle back to the OP's original usages. Note that "the evening, gloomy, rainy, and cold" doesn't include a verb. A dressmaking parallel, with more context, might be "she wore a lovely dress, white, lacy, and voluminous." In all this talk about how we can chain adjectives together without commas, perhaps it is worth reassuring the OP that they were correct to use them in this situation.

@AndyBonner Not sure why you're now talking about verbs. It's a given that all complete sentences contain a verb. I would presume that the OP's sentences are not complete and might be part of a sentence like "he waited through the evening, rainy and cold". Likewise, you could say "she wore a dress, bright red cotton and fitting like a glove".
